# Wifi constantly dropping at University

Tags: 13.10, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T440s with the Intel 7620 AC card. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and while I'm at school my Wifi drops constantly. I don't experience this issue when I'm in Windows. I was wondering if anyone knows of a fix to this as it's quite annoying.

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers? -> https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Seems like a windows utility

Comment: Your wifi card drivers can be different in Linux than Windows, which can caused different issues. Can you do a speedtest or even a ping command to see how your connection holds on Ubuntu?